# Batch delete invalid short-cuts

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, shortcut, delete-file

How would I make a batch file that would search a computer for all invalid short-cuts (short-cuts that don't link to a file that isn't there any more.) and remove them. It can be done preferable in batch but VBScript is OK if there are problems doing it in batch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a vbscript to do it.

```
DeleteShortCut "C:\"


Sub DeleteShortcut(Folder)
    For Each Subfolder in Folder.SubFolders
        Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Subfolder.Path)
        Set colFiles = objFolder.Files 
        For Each objFile in colFiles
            If  objFile.Name <> "Desktop.lnk"  And  UCase(objFile.Type) = "SHORTCUT" Then 
                Set objshortcut = objshell.CreateShortcut(objFile.Path)
                filepath =  objshortcut.TargetPath 
                If objFSO.FileExists(filepath) = False Then 
                    WScript.Echo  "Removing invalid ShortCut :" & objFile.Path
                    objFSO.DeleteFile(objFile.Path) 
                End If 
            End If    
        Next
        DeleteShortcut Subfolder
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

To give something back. KIX works better for me and I made this script for removing Citrix pnagen.exe LNK files from a user as Receiver 4.3 does not clean up during install:

```
;---------------------------------------------------------------------
; Filename..: RemoveIcaLNK.kix
; Author....: Arild Skullerud inspired by enumfiles by David M. Stein
; Date......: 09/24/15
; Purpose...: Remove all LNK files with a set of folders
;             Removes only LNK files pointing to:
;               "C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\ICA Client\pnagent.exe"
;             Created with the purpose of cleaning up LNK files before
;             installing Citrix Receiver 4.3 as it fails cleaning up.
;---------------------------------------------------------------------

; Simple folders I could remove in a simple way
RD ("%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\XenApp\") /s
RD ("%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Metaframe\") /s

;--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Deletes $lnkfilepath pointing to the lnk file to be deleted
; $targetpath is the EXE the lnk points to ( or any other filetype)
;--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Function WshRmInvShortCut($lnkfilepath,$targetpath)
dim $shell,$shortcut
$shell = createobject("wscript.shell")
if $shell
  $shortcut = $shell.createshortcut("$lnkfilepath")
  if $shortcut
   if $shortcut.targetpath=$targetpath 
   ; Some debug lines
   ;? $shortcut.targetpath
   ;? $lnkfilepath
    ; Delete only the LNK file that points to the correct exe here
    ;DEL ($lnkfilepath) /h /s
    $shortcut = 0
   endif
  endif
  $shell = 0
endif
exit @error
EndFunction

;--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Searches $StartPath for files ending with $ext and calls WshRmInvShortCut for removing them
; $targetpath is the exe the lnk points to
;--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Function Enum_Files($StartPath, $Ext)
    Dim $fName
    $fName = Dir("$StartPath\*.$Ext")
    While $fName <> "" And @ERROR = 0
        WshRmInvShortCut($StartPath+\+$fname,$targetpath)
        $fName = Dir()
    Loop
EndFunction

;--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; Script running from here
; Path to pnagent.exe
$targetpath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\ICA Client\pnagent.exe"
; Filename ending
$Ext = "lnk"

; Path to folder I want to search and empty of lnk files
$StartPath="%appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"
; Calling script for first path
$=Enum_Files($StartPath, $Ext)

; Path to folder I want to search and empty of lnk files
$StartPath="%userprofile%\Desktop"
; Calling script for second path
$=Enum_Files($StartPath, $Ext)

:END
```